# Do basket options have a closed form valuation formula?

Tags: options, option-pricing, simulations, european-options, basket

Suppose I'm simulating a European call option on a basket consisting of N stocks with slightly varying volatilities but all other parameters remain the same. From the perspective of an estimate, it seems simple to aggregate the values at expiry from a Monte Carlo simulation and subtract the strike of the basket. However, I'm wondering if there's a closed form equation to value basket options, ideally based off of the Black Scholes PDE, that could be used to compute the exact value as a comparison.

Edit: I edited to clarify what I meant by an option basket

Comment: What do you mean with a basket of N European call options? I think you mean you want to price an European option on a basket of N stocks/indices, but just making certain.

Comment: That was my assumption too!

Comment: @StackG has an excellent answer below (he/she provides good ways to deal with the lack of closed-form solutions, I upvoted).  Since you do not necessarily require the Black-Scholes framework, you _could_ assume your forward distributions are gaussian rather than lognormal (multivariate Bachelier model).  You would then obtain a closed-form pricing formula, and it would work pretty well for short tenors.  I've never tried it because moment matching (as StackG cites) is really the best approach.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not completely certain from your question, but I'm going to assume you have a basket of $n$ stocks with prices $S_0(t)$ to $S_n(t)$, and you want to price an option with payoff at $C(\tau)$ at time $\tau$ equal to

\begin{align}
C(\tau) = \max\Bigl({\frac 1 n}\sum^n_{i=1} S_i - K, 0\Bigr)
\end{align}
where $K$ is the strike of the option

I'm also going to make BS assumptions that each of these evolves according to geometric brownian motion in the RN measure, so

\begin{align}
dS_i = S_i \bigl(r dt + \sigma_i dW_t)
\end{align}
where the brownian motions are potentially correlated with $n \times n$ correlation matrix $\tilde{\Sigma}$

This means that at time $\tau$, each of the stocks has a price
\begin{align}
S_i(\tau) &= S_i(0)\exp \Bigl( (r -{\frac 1 2} \sigma_i^2)\tau + \sigma_i \sqrt{\tau} x_i \Bigr)\\
&= F_i(0) \exp \Bigl( {\frac 1 2} \sigma_i^2\tau + \sigma_i \sqrt{\tau} x_i \Bigr)
\end{align}
where I have absorbed the $r$ term into the forward to simplify algebra, and the $x_i$ are variables drawn from an $n$-dimensional multivariate normal with mean $0$, variance $1$ and correlation matrix $\tilde{\Sigma}$ from above

Now the problem we face is that assuming these dynamics, we know how to price an option on a single stock, whose price is lognormally distributed, using the BS formula. But unfortunately, the $\sum^n_{i=0} S_i$ term in the payoff is not lognormally distributed because it's a sum of lognormals, not a product.

We have two choices:

1. **Price numerically using Monte-Carlo**

Here is python to do that (here, for 5 stocks with an random correlation matrix I just made up)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

means = np.zeros(5)
corr_mat = np.matrix([[1, 0.1, -0.1, 0, 0], [0.1, 1, 0, 0, 0.2], [-0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0.15], [0, 0.2, 0, 0.15, 1]])
vols = np.array([0.1, 0.12, 0.13, 0.09, 0.11])

cov_mat = np.diag(vols).dot(corr_mat).dot(np.diag(vols))

initial_spots = np.array([100., 100., 100., 100., 100.])
tte = 1.0
strike = 100
seed = 43
num_paths = 50000

results = []
rng = multivariate_normal(means, cov_mat).rvs(size=num_paths, random_state=seed)

for i in range(num_paths):
    rns = rng[i]
    final_spots = initial_spots * np.exp(-0.5*vols*vols*tte) * np.exp(tte * rns)
    results.append(final_spots)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df['payoff'] = ((df.sum(axis=1) / 5) - strike).clip(0)

df['payoff'].mean()
```

gives price $\sim 2.09$

2. **Price *APPROXIMATELY*, using analytical techniques**

We can use a trick here. The price of the sum of the options is not lognormally distributed, but the product of the prices is, so we **CAN** analytically price the contract with payoff
\begin{align}
C(\tau) = \max\Bigl(\bigl(\prod^n_{i=1} S_i\bigr)^{\frac 1 n} - K, 0\Bigr)
\end{align}

The algebra is a bit involved (see bottom of answer), but it turns out that this simplifies to a vanilla option pricing problem, so we can price the option using the regular BS equations:
\begin{align}
C(0) &= \delta \bigl(F\Phi(d_{+}) - K \Phi(d_{-})\bigr)\\
d_{+} &= {\frac {\ln{\frac F K} + {\frac 1 2} \tilde{\sigma}^2 \tau} {\tilde{\sigma}\sqrt{\tau}}}\\
d_{-} &= d_{+} - \tilde{\sigma}\sqrt{\tau}
\end{align}

but the values that we need to insert for $F$ and $\tilde{\sigma}$ are:
\begin{align}
\sigma^2 &= {\frac 1 n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2\\
\tilde{\sigma}^2 &= {\frac 1 {n^2}} \sum_{i,j=0}^n \rho_{ij} \sigma_i \sigma_j\\
F &= \Bigl(\prod_{i=1}^n F_i\Bigr)^{\frac 1 n} \cdot \exp\Bigl(-{\frac 1 2} \bigl(\sigma^2 - \tilde{\sigma}^2 \bigr)\tau\Bigr)
\end{align}

I've implemented that in scruffy python here as well:

```
mod_vol_1 = (vols ** 2).mean()
mod_vol_2 = vols.dot(corr).dot(vols) / len(vols)**2

mod_fwd = np.product(initial_spots)**(1/len(vols)) * np.exp(-0.5*tte*(mod_vol_1 - mod_vol_2))

d_plus = (np.log(mod_fwd / strike) + 0.5 * mod_vol_2 * tte) / np.sqrt(mod_vol_2 * tte)
d_minus = d_plus - np.sqrt(mod_vol_2 * tte)

mod_fwd * norm.cdf(d_plus) - strike * norm.cdf(d_minus)
```

price is $1.87$

How does this help us? Actually in two ways...

- **Moment Matching**

This was developed for the geometric averaging basket, but it turns out that we can use a technique called [Moment Matching](https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Edbrigo/basketkli.pdf) to improve the approximation

To first order, this gives us the same equations as above except that $F$ is instead equal to simply
\begin{align}
F &= \Bigl(\prod_{i=1}^n F_i\Bigr)^{\frac 1 n}
\end{align}

If we make this adjustment to our scruffy python, we match the Monte-Carlo price above almost exactly...

```
mod_vol_1 = (vols ** 2).mean()
mod_vol_2 = vols.dot(corr).dot(vols) / len(vols)**2

mod_fwd = np.product(initial_spots)**(1/len(vols))

d_plus = (np.log(mod_fwd / strike) + 0.5 * mod_vol_2 * tte) / np.sqrt(mod_vol_2 * tte)
d_minus = d_plus - np.sqrt(mod_vol_2 * tte)

mod_fwd * norm.cdf(d_plus) - strike * norm.cdf(d_minus)
```

price is $2.10$

- **Control Variates**

We can also use the geometric option to improve our MC calculation, using the technique of [Control Variates](http://www.quantopia.net/improving-monte-carlo-control-variates/), which relies on the fact that because the price of the two types of option are highly correlated, MC paths that over-price one will tend to over-price the other, and vice-versa, which allows us to improve the convergence of the MC greatly.

And they are indeed highly correlated... here is a scatter plot of the two prices along the same paths (note the geometric basket is always cheaper than the arithmetic basket along a given path):

[image: Geometric vs Arithmetic Baskets]

Answer (score 4):

In addition to StackG's answer, here is a good introductory overview of several (approximate and semi-analytical) methods to price baskets in a Black-Scholes framework:

[Krekel et al - An analysis of pricing methods for basket options](https://scholar.google.nl/scholar?cluster=866282096263303311&hl=nl&as_sdt=0,5)

Answer (score 1):

There are many approximations for basket options, they all make different assumptions.  The most accurate one cited for European baskets that have only positive weights is Ju 2002, which uses a Taylor expansion.  If you want to take a look at a few implementations you can find one in MATLAB (type: `open basketsensbyju.m`) and one in Python (PyFENG package, multiasset_Ju2002.py), `pip install pyfeng`.  https://github.com/PyFE/PyFENG - this package also has quite a few other models for Euro baskets implemented in multiasset.py, including a couple using ABM that can handle negative weights.